# How do I get value from one column by giving values of other two columns in Sqlite Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have 4 columns in my database which are name, lat, lng and pno. Now i've passed the values of lat and long into a string variable from another activity of whose pno I want. What select statement should I write to get the respective pno of the lat and lng into a String Variable. I am new to android please help.

Comment: It is basically an SQL query problem that you can easily find it by google search.

Answer (score 0):

try this SQL query

```
select  pno from yourTable where lat='lat value' and lng='lng value';
```